# How to rearrange this function to return the extended list in Haskell

Tags: function, haskell, list-comprehension

I am  doing [problem 68](http://projecteuler.net/index.php?section=problems&id=68) at project euler and came up with the following code in Haskell to return the list of numbers which fit the (given) solution:

```
lists = [n|n<- permutations [1..6] , ring n ] 
ring [a,b,c,d,e,f] = (length $ nub $ map sum [[d,c,b],[f,b,a],[e,a,c]]) == 1
```

This only returns a list of lists of 6 numbers each which fit the solution. What I don't know how to do, is make it return the actual solution, the  lists that fit the form:

```
[d,c,b],[f,b,a],[e,a,c]
```

How can I make `lists` return a list of this format?

(PS: I will add in the appropriate functions to return what the site actually wants later)

Comment: BTW, I'm sure you've seen this already, but the Euler problems are very well documented on the Haskell Wiki (http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Euler_problems)

Comment: But that might be considered cheating. And I would rather learn by figuring how I do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply

```
lists = [ [[d,c,b],[f,b,a],[e,a,c]] | n@[a,b,c,d,e,f] <- permutations [1..6], ring n ]
```

Or in order to generate the strings:

```
[ foldl (++) "" $ map show [d,c,b,f,b,a,e,a,c] | n@[a,b,c,d,e,f] <- permutations [1..6], ring n ]
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I never knew about `@`.

Comment: On a further note, I keep getting an incorrect answer of: 432513621 (real answer is: 432621513). I used: `answer = read $ concatMap show $ maximum $ map concat $ map sort lists :: Integer`

Care to shed any light on where I am going wrong?